# Create Columnline inside a grid with gap

Tags: html, css, sass

Hello I struggle for days with this css problem.
I can't figure out how to create a straight line for the first column. I tried it using another div inside the span and placing it with position absolute but when using a scrollpane for smaller devices the border keeps when scrolling, when using zero gap and create a grid through padding inside the elements I get the line but my elements doesnt have an even gap everywhere and the index number on the left stays bigger causing a much bigger gap.
I would be very thankful if someone could help me.

```
fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/43oaq8ts/8/
```

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

> Check out this/

```css
        $blue: #0084ff;
        $blue-darker: darken($blue, 5);

        body {
          background: white;
          padding: 20px;
          font-family: Helvetica;
        }


        .konzgrid {
          display: grid;
          aspect-ratio: 1;
          grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
          grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 0fr);
          grid-gap: 0;
          * {
            aspect-ratio: 1;
          }
        }
        .index {
          vertical-align: middle;
          span {
            display: flex;
            margin: auto;
            line-height: 100%;
            font-weight: bold;
          }
          position: relative;
          border-right: solid black 2px;
        }
        .konzitem {
        padding:5px;
          display: block;
          * {
            display: flex;
            vertical-align: middle;
          }
        }
```

```html
        <div class="konzwrapper p-2" style="display: inline-block;">
          <div class="konzgrid" style="gap: 0px 2px;">
            <div class="konzitem index" style="width: 15px; height: 19px; background-color: pink;"><span>1</span></div>
            <div id="Reihe 0 Zeichen0" class="konzitem" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 79.7 79.7">
                <g id="Ebene_2" data-name="Ebene 2">
                  <path d="M74.7,5V74.7H5V5H74.7m0-5H5A5,5,0,0,0,0,5V74.7a5,5,0,0,0,5,5H74.7a5,5,0,0,0,5-5V5a5,5,0,0,0-5-5Z"></path>
                  <path d="M50.79,36.31H74.7a0,0,0,0,1,0,0v7.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H50.79a2.57,2.57,0,0,1-2.57-2.57V38.88A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,50.79,36.31Z"></path>
                  <path d="M29.18,14.7H53.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0v7.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H29.18a2.57,2.57,0,0,1-2.57-2.57V17.27A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,29.18,14.7Z" transform="translate(21.61 58.09) rotate(-90)"></path>
                </g>
              </svg></div>
            <div id="Reihe 0 Zeichen1" class="richtig konzitem" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 79.7 79.7">
                <g id="Ebene_2" data-name="Ebene 2">
                  <path d="M74.7,5V74.7H5V5H74.7m0-5H5A5,5,0,0,0,0,5V74.7a5,5,0,0,0,5,5H74.7a5,5,0,0,0,5-5V5a5,5,0,0,0-5-5Z"></path>
                  <path d="M29.18,57.92H53.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0V65a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H29.18a2.57,2.57,0,0,1-2.57-2.57V60.49A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,29.18,57.92Z" transform="translate(101.31 21.61) rotate(90)"></path>
                  <path d="M50.79,36.31H74.7a0,0,0,0,1,0,0v7.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H50.79a2.57,2.57,0,0,1-2.57-2.57V38.88A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,50.79,36.31Z"></path>
                  <path d="M7.57,36.31H31.48a0,0,0,0,1,0,0v7.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H7.57A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,5,40.82V38.88A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,7.57,36.31Z" transform="translate(36.48 79.7) rotate(180)"></path>
                </g>
              </svg></div>
            <div id="Reihe 0 Zeichen2" class="richtig konzitem" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 79.7 79.7">
                <g id="Ebene_2" data-name="Ebene 2">
                  <path d="M74.7,5V74.7H5V5H74.7m0-5H5A5,5,0,0,0,0,5V74.7a5,5,0,0,0,5,5H74.7a5,5,0,0,0,5-5V5a5,5,0,0,0-5-5Z"></path>
                  <path d="M7.57,36.31H31.48a0,0,0,0,1,0,0v7.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H7.57A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,5,40.82V38.88A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,7.57,36.31Z" transform="translate(36.48 79.7) rotate(180)"></path>
                  <path d="M29.18,14.7H53.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0v7.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H29.18a2.57,2.57,0,0,1-2.57-2.57V17.27A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,29.18,14.7Z" transform="translate(21.61 58.09) rotate(-90)"></path>
                </g>
              </svg></div>
            <div id="Reihe 0 Zeichen3" class="richtig konzitem" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 79.7 79.7">
                <g id="Ebene_2" data-name="Ebene 2">
                  <path d="M74.7,5V74.7H5V5H74.7m0-5H5A5,5,0,0,0,0,5V74.7a5,5,0,0,0,5,5H74.7a5,5,0,0,0,5-5V5a5,5,0,0,0-5-5Z"></path>
                  <path d="M29.18,57.92H53.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0V65a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H29.18a2.57,2.57,0,0,1-2.57-2.57V60.49A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,29.18,57.92Z" transform="translate(101.31 21.61) rotate(90)"></path>
                  <path d="M7.57,36.31H31.48a0,0,0,0,1,0,0v7.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H7.57A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,5,40.82V38.88A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,7.57,36.31Z" transform="translate(36.48 79.7) rotate(180)"></path>
                </g>
              </svg></div>
            <div id="Reihe 0 Zeichen4" class="richtig konzitem" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 79.7 79.7">
                <g id="Ebene_2" data-name="Ebene 2">
                  <path d="M74.7,5V74.7H5V5H74.7m0-5H5A5,5,0,0,0,0,5V74.7a5,5,0,0,0,5,5H74.7a5,5,0,0,0,5-5V5a5,5,0,0,0-5-5Z"></path>
                  <path d="M50.79,36.31H74.7a0,0,0,0,1,0,0v7.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H50.79a2.57,2.57,0,0,1-2.57-2.57V38.88A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,50.79,36.31Z"></path>
                  <path d="M29.18,14.7H53.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0v7.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H29.18a2.57,2.57,0,0,1-2.57-2.57V17.27A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,29.18,14.7Z" transform="translate(21.61 58.09) rotate(-90)"></path>
                </g>
              </svg></div>
            <div class="konzitem index" style="width: 15px; height: 19px; background-color: pink;"><span>2</span></div>
            <div id="Reihe 1 Zeichen0" class="richtig konzitem" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 79.7 79.7">
                <g id="Ebene_2" data-name="Ebene 2">
                  <path d="M74.7,5V74.7H5V5H74.7m0-5H5A5,5,0,0,0,0,5V74.7a5,5,0,0,0,5,5H74.7a5,5,0,0,0,5-5V5a5,5,0,0,0-5-5Z"></path>
                  <path d="M50.79,36.31H74.7a0,0,0,0,1,0,0v7.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H50.79a2.57,2.57,0,0,1-2.57-2.57V38.88A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,50.79,36.31Z"></path>
                  <path d="M7.57,36.31H31.48a0,0,0,0,1,0,0v7.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H7.57A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,5,40.82V38.88A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,7.57,36.31Z" transform="translate(36.48 79.7) rotate(180)"></path>
                </g>
              </svg></div>
            <div id="Reihe 1 Zeichen1" class="richtig konzitem" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 79.7 79.7">
                <g id="Ebene_2" data-name="Ebene 2">
                  <path d="M74.7,5V74.7H5V5H74.7m0-5H5A5,5,0,0,0,0,5V74.7a5,5,0,0,0,5,5H74.7a5,5,0,0,0,5-5V5a5,5,0,0,0-5-5Z"></path>
                  <path d="M50.79,36.31H74.7a0,0,0,0,1,0,0v7.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H50.79a2.57,2.57,0,0,1-2.57-2.57V38.88A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,50.79,36.31Z"></path>
                  <path d="M7.57,36.31H31.48a0,0,0,0,1,0,0v7.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H7.57A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,5,40.82V38.88A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,7.57,36.31Z" transform="translate(36.48 79.7) rotate(180)"></path>
                  <path d="M29.18,14.7H53.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0v7.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H29.18a2.57,2.57,0,0,1-2.57-2.57V17.27A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,29.18,14.7Z" transform="translate(21.61 58.09) rotate(-90)"></path>
                </g>
              </svg></div>
            <div id="Reihe 1 Zeichen2" class="richtig konzitem" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 79.7 79.7">
                <g id="Ebene_2" data-name="Ebene 2">
                  <path d="M74.7,5V74.7H5V5H74.7m0-5H5A5,5,0,0,0,0,5V74.7a5,5,0,0,0,5,5H74.7a5,5,0,0,0,5-5V5a5,5,0,0,0-5-5Z"></path>
                  <path d="M7.57,36.31H31.48a0,0,0,0,1,0,0v7.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H7.57A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,5,40.82V38.88A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,7.57,36.31Z" transform="translate(36.48 79.7) rotate(180)"></path>
                  <path d="M29.18,14.7H53.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0v7.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H29.18a2.57,2.57,0,0,1-2.57-2.57V17.27A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,29.18,14.7Z" transform="translate(21.61 58.09) rotate(-90)"></path>
                </g>
              </svg></div>
            <div id="Reihe 1 Zeichen3" class="richtig konzitem" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 79.7 79.7">
                <g id="Ebene_2" data-name="Ebene 2">
                  <path d="M74.7,5V74.7H5V5H74.7m0-5H5A5,5,0,0,0,0,5V74.7a5,5,0,0,0,5,5H74.7a5,5,0,0,0,5-5V5a5,5,0,0,0-5-5Z"></path>
                  <path d="M7.57,36.31H31.48a0,0,0,0,1,0,0v7.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H7.57A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,5,40.82V38.88A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,7.57,36.31Z" transform="translate(36.48 79.7) rotate(180)"></path>
                  <path d="M29.18,14.7H53.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0v7.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H29.18a2.57,2.57,0,0,1-2.57-2.57V17.27A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,29.18,14.7Z" transform="translate(21.61 58.09) rotate(-90)"></path>
                </g>
              </svg></div>
            <div id="Reihe 1 Zeichen4" class="richtig konzitem" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 79.7 79.7">
                <g id="Ebene_2" data-name="Ebene 2">
                  <path d="M74.7,5V74.7H5V5H74.7m0-5H5A5,5,0,0,0,0,5V74.7a5,5,0,0,0,5,5H74.7a5,5,0,0,0,5-5V5a5,5,0,0,0-5-5Z"></path>
                  <path d="M29.18,57.92H53.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0V65a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H29.18a2.57,2.57,0,0,1-2.57-2.57V60.49A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,29.18,57.92Z" transform="translate(101.31 21.61) rotate(90)"></path>
                  <path d="M50.79,36.31H74.7a0,0,0,0,1,0,0v7.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H50.79a2.57,2.57,0,0,1-2.57-2.57V38.88A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,50.79,36.31Z"></path>
                </g>
              </svg></div>
            <div class="konzitem index" style="width: 15px; height: 19px; background-color: pink;"><span>3</span></div>
            <div id="Reihe 2 Zeichen0" class="richtig konzitem" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 79.7 79.7">
                <g id="Ebene_2" data-name="Ebene 2">
                  <path d="M74.7,5V74.7H5V5H74.7m0-5H5A5,5,0,0,0,0,5V74.7a5,5,0,0,0,5,5H74.7a5,5,0,0,0,5-5V5a5,5,0,0,0-5-5Z"></path>
                  <path d="M7.57,36.31H31.48a0,0,0,0,1,0,0v7.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H7.57A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,5,40.82V38.88A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,7.57,36.31Z" transform="translate(36.48 79.7) rotate(180)"></path>
                  <path d="M29.18,14.7H53.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0v7.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H29.18a2.57,2.57,0,0,1-2.57-2.57V17.27A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,29.18,14.7Z" transform="translate(21.61 58.09) rotate(-90)"></path>
                </g>
              </svg></div>
            <div id="Reihe 2 Zeichen1" class="richtig konzitem" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 79.7 79.7">
                <g id="Ebene_2" data-name="Ebene 2">
                  <path d="M74.7,5V74.7H5V5H74.7m0-5H5A5,5,0,0,0,0,5V74.7a5,5,0,0,0,5,5H74.7a5,5,0,0,0,5-5V5a5,5,0,0,0-5-5Z"></path>
                  <path d="M50.79,36.31H74.7a0,0,0,0,1,0,0v7.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H50.79a2.57,2.57,0,0,1-2.57-2.57V38.88A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,50.79,36.31Z"></path>
                  <path d="M29.18,14.7H53.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0v7.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H29.18a2.57,2.57,0,0,1-2.57-2.57V17.27A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,29.18,14.7Z" transform="translate(21.61 58.09) rotate(-90)"></path>
                </g>
              </svg></div>
            <div id="Reihe 2 Zeichen2" class="richtig konzitem" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 79.7 79.7">
                <g id="Ebene_2" data-name="Ebene 2">
                  <path d="M74.7,5V74.7H5V5H74.7m0-5H5A5,5,0,0,0,0,5V74.7a5,5,0,0,0,5,5H74.7a5,5,0,0,0,5-5V5a5,5,0,0,0-5-5Z"></path>
                  <path d="M50.79,36.31H74.7a0,0,0,0,1,0,0v7.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H50.79a2.57,2.57,0,0,1-2.57-2.57V38.88A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,50.79,36.31Z"></path>
                  <path d="M29.18,14.7H53.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0v7.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H29.18a2.57,2.57,0,0,1-2.57-2.57V17.27A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,29.18,14.7Z" transform="translate(21.61 58.09) rotate(-90)"></path>
                </g>
              </svg></div>
            <div id="Reihe 2 Zeichen3" class="richtig konzitem" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 79.7 79.7">
                <g id="Ebene_2" data-name="Ebene 2">
                  <path d="M74.7,5V74.7H5V5H74.7m0-5H5A5,5,0,0,0,0,5V74.7a5,5,0,0,0,5,5H74.7a5,5,0,0,0,5-5V5a5,5,0,0,0-5-5Z"></path>
                  <path d="M50.79,36.31H74.7a0,0,0,0,1,0,0v7.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H50.79a2.57,2.57,0,0,1-2.57-2.57V38.88A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,50.79,36.31Z"></path>
                  <path d="M29.18,14.7H53.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0v7.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H29.18a2.57,2.57,0,0,1-2.57-2.57V17.27A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,29.18,14.7Z" transform="translate(21.61 58.09) rotate(-90)"></path>
                </g>
              </svg></div>
            <div id="Reihe 2 Zeichen4" class="richtig konzitem" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 79.7 79.7">
                <g id="Ebene_2" data-name="Ebene 2">
                  <path d="M74.7,5V74.7H5V5H74.7m0-5H5A5,5,0,0,0,0,5V74.7a5,5,0,0,0,5,5H74.7a5,5,0,0,0,5-5V5a5,5,0,0,0-5-5Z"></path>
                  <path d="M50.79,36.31H74.7a0,0,0,0,1,0,0v7.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H50.79a2.57,2.57,0,0,1-2.57-2.57V38.88A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,50.79,36.31Z"></path>
                  <path d="M29.18,14.7H53.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0v7.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H29.18a2.57,2.57,0,0,1-2.57-2.57V17.27A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,29.18,14.7Z" transform="translate(21.61 58.09) rotate(-90)"></path>
                </g>
              </svg></div>
            <div class="konzitem index" style="width: 15px; height: 19px; background-color: pink;"><span>4</span></div>
            <div id="Reihe 3 Zeichen0" class="richtig konzitem" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 79.7 79.7">
                <g id="Ebene_2" data-name="Ebene 2">
                  <path d="M74.7,5V74.7H5V5H74.7m0-5H5A5,5,0,0,0,0,5V74.7a5,5,0,0,0,5,5H74.7a5,5,0,0,0,5-5V5a5,5,0,0,0-5-5Z"></path>
                  <path d="M29.18,57.92H53.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0V65a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H29.18a2.57,2.57,0,0,1-2.57-2.57V60.49A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,29.18,57.92Z" transform="translate(101.31 21.61) rotate(90)"></path>
                  <path d="M50.79,36.31H74.7a0,0,0,0,1,0,0v7.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H50.79a2.57,2.57,0,0,1-2.57-2.57V38.88A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,50.79,36.31Z"></path>
                  <path d="M29.18,14.7H53.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0v7.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H29.18a2.57,2.57,0,0,1-2.57-2.57V17.27A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,29.18,14.7Z" transform="translate(21.61 58.09) rotate(-90)"></path>
                </g>
              </svg></div>
            <div id="Reihe 3 Zeichen1" class="richtig konzitem" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 79.7 79.7">
                <g id="Ebene_2" data-name="Ebene 2">
                  <path d="M74.7,5V74.7H5V5H74.7m0-5H5A5,5,0,0,0,0,5V74.7a5,5,0,0,0,5,5H74.7a5,5,0,0,0,5-5V5a5,5,0,0,0-5-5Z"></path>
                  <path d="M29.18,57.92H53.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0V65a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H29.18a2.57,2.57,0,0,1-2.57-2.57V60.49A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,29.18,57.92Z" transform="translate(101.31 21.61) rotate(90)"></path>
                  <path d="M50.79,36.31H74.7a0,0,0,0,1,0,0v7.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H50.79a2.57,2.57,0,0,1-2.57-2.57V38.88A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,50.79,36.31Z"></path>
                </g>
              </svg></div>
            <div id="Reihe 3 Zeichen2" class="richtig konzitem" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 79.7 79.7">
                <g id="Ebene_2" data-name="Ebene 2">
                  <path d="M74.7,5V74.7H5V5H74.7m0-5H5A5,5,0,0,0,0,5V74.7a5,5,0,0,0,5,5H74.7a5,5,0,0,0,5-5V5a5,5,0,0,0-5-5Z"></path>
                  <path d="M50.79,36.31H74.7a0,0,0,0,1,0,0v7.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H50.79a2.57,2.57,0,0,1-2.57-2.57V38.88A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,50.79,36.31Z"></path>
                  <path d="M7.57,36.31H31.48a0,0,0,0,1,0,0v7.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H7.57A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,5,40.82V38.88A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,7.57,36.31Z" transform="translate(36.48 79.7) rotate(180)"></path>
                  <path d="M29.18,14.7H53.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0v7.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H29.18a2.57,2.57,0,0,1-2.57-2.57V17.27A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,29.18,14.7Z" transform="translate(21.61 58.09) rotate(-90)"></path>
                </g>
              </svg></div>
            <div id="Reihe 3 Zeichen3" class="richtig konzitem" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 79.7 79.7">
                <g id="Ebene_2" data-name="Ebene 2">
                  <path d="M74.7,5V74.7H5V5H74.7m0-5H5A5,5,0,0,0,0,5V74.7a5,5,0,0,0,5,5H74.7a5,5,0,0,0,5-5V5a5,5,0,0,0-5-5Z"></path>
                  <path d="M50.79,36.31H74.7a0,0,0,0,1,0,0v7.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H50.79a2.57,2.57,0,0,1-2.57-2.57V38.88A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,50.79,36.31Z"></path>
                  <path d="M29.18,14.7H53.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0v7.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H29.18a2.57,2.57,0,0,1-2.57-2.57V17.27A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,29.18,14.7Z" transform="translate(21.61 58.09) rotate(-90)"></path>
                </g>
              </svg></div>
            <div id="Reihe 3 Zeichen4" class="richtig konzitem" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 79.7 79.7">
                <g id="Ebene_2" data-name="Ebene 2">
                  <path d="M74.7,5V74.7H5V5H74.7m0-5H5A5,5,0,0,0,0,5V74.7a5,5,0,0,0,5,5H74.7a5,5,0,0,0,5-5V5a5,5,0,0,0-5-5Z"></path>
                  <path d="M50.79,36.31H74.7a0,0,0,0,1,0,0v7.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H50.79a2.57,2.57,0,0,1-2.57-2.57V38.88A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,50.79,36.31Z"></path>
                  <path d="M7.57,36.31H31.48a0,0,0,0,1,0,0v7.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H7.57A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,5,40.82V38.88A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,7.57,36.31Z" transform="translate(36.48 79.7) rotate(180)"></path>
                </g>
              </svg></div>
            <div class="konzitem index" style="width: 15px; height: 19px; background-color: pink;"><span>5</span></div>
            <div id="Reihe 4 Zeichen0" class="richtig konzitem" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 79.7 79.7">
                <g id="Ebene_2" data-name="Ebene 2">
                  <path d="M74.7,5V74.7H5V5H74.7m0-5H5A5,5,0,0,0,0,5V74.7a5,5,0,0,0,5,5H74.7a5,5,0,0,0,5-5V5a5,5,0,0,0-5-5Z"></path>
                  <path d="M29.18,57.92H53.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0V65a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H29.18a2.57,2.57,0,0,1-2.57-2.57V60.49A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,29.18,57.92Z" transform="translate(101.31 21.61) rotate(90)"></path>
                  <path d="M7.57,36.31H31.48a0,0,0,0,1,0,0v7.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H7.57A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,5,40.82V38.88A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,7.57,36.31Z" transform="translate(36.48 79.7) rotate(180)"></path>
                  <path d="M29.18,14.7H53.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0v7.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H29.18a2.57,2.57,0,0,1-2.57-2.57V17.27A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,29.18,14.7Z" transform="translate(21.61 58.09) rotate(-90)"></path>
                </g>
              </svg></div>
            <div id="Reihe 4 Zeichen1" class="richtig konzitem" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 79.7 79.7">
                <g id="Ebene_2" data-name="Ebene 2">
                  <path d="M74.7,5V74.7H5V5H74.7m0-5H5A5,5,0,0,0,0,5V74.7a5,5,0,0,0,5,5H74.7a5,5,0,0,0,5-5V5a5,5,0,0,0-5-5Z"></path>
                  <path d="M7.57,36.31H31.48a0,0,0,0,1,0,0v7.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H7.57A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,5,40.82V38.88A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,7.57,36.31Z" transform="translate(36.48 79.7) rotate(180)"></path>
                  <path d="M29.18,14.7H53.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0v7.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H29.18a2.57,2.57,0,0,1-2.57-2.57V17.27A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,29.18,14.7Z" transform="translate(21.61 58.09) rotate(-90)"></path>
                </g>
              </svg></div>
            <div id="Reihe 4 Zeichen2" class="richtig konzitem" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 79.7 79.7">
                <g id="Ebene_2" data-name="Ebene 2">
                  <path d="M74.7,5V74.7H5V5H74.7m0-5H5A5,5,0,0,0,0,5V74.7a5,5,0,0,0,5,5H74.7a5,5,0,0,0,5-5V5a5,5,0,0,0-5-5Z"></path>
                  <path d="M29.18,57.92H53.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0V65a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H29.18a2.57,2.57,0,0,1-2.57-2.57V60.49A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,29.18,57.92Z" transform="translate(101.31 21.61) rotate(90)"></path>
                  <path d="M7.57,36.31H31.48a0,0,0,0,1,0,0v7.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H7.57A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,5,40.82V38.88A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,7.57,36.31Z" transform="translate(36.48 79.7) rotate(180)"></path>
                  <path d="M29.18,14.7H53.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0v7.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H29.18a2.57,2.57,0,0,1-2.57-2.57V17.27A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,29.18,14.7Z" transform="translate(21.61 58.09) rotate(-90)"></path>
                </g>
              </svg></div>
            <div id="Reihe 4 Zeichen3" class="richtig konzitem" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 79.7 79.7">
                <g id="Ebene_2" data-name="Ebene 2">
                  <path d="M74.7,5V74.7H5V5H74.7m0-5H5A5,5,0,0,0,0,5V74.7a5,5,0,0,0,5,5H74.7a5,5,0,0,0,5-5V5a5,5,0,0,0-5-5Z"></path>
                  <path d="M7.57,36.31H31.48a0,0,0,0,1,0,0v7.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H7.57A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,5,40.82V38.88A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,7.57,36.31Z" transform="translate(36.48 79.7) rotate(180)"></path>
                  <path d="M29.18,14.7H53.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0v7.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H29.18a2.57,2.57,0,0,1-2.57-2.57V17.27A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,29.18,14.7Z" transform="translate(21.61 58.09) rotate(-90)"></path>
                </g>
              </svg></div>
            <div id="Reihe 4 Zeichen4" class="richtig konzitem" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 79.7 79.7">
                <g id="Ebene_2" data-name="Ebene 2">
                  <path d="M74.7,5V74.7H5V5H74.7m0-5H5A5,5,0,0,0,0,5V74.7a5,5,0,0,0,5,5H74.7a5,5,0,0,0,5-5V5a5,5,0,0,0-5-5Z"></path>
                  <path d="M7.57,36.31H31.48a0,0,0,0,1,0,0v7.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H7.57A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,5,40.82V38.88A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,7.57,36.31Z" transform="translate(36.48 79.7) rotate(180)"></path>
                  <path d="M29.18,14.7H53.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0v7.09a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H29.18a2.57,2.57,0,0,1-2.57-2.57V17.27A2.57,2.57,0,0,1,29.18,14.7Z" transform="translate(21.61 58.09) rotate(-90)"></path>
                </g>
              </svg></div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Pretty much only that the distance between the elements on the left and right are a little bigger than on top, what exactly did u change.
I see you changed the gap to 0 but how is it that the divs have still a gap :/ A flaw in my fiddle?

Comment: I used `gap:0 5px` instead of `gap:2px`! You can set this to `gap:0 2px`.

Comment: The reason for the distance from the top and bottom is the low height of the svgs

Comment: Okay so the problem is a i need a consistent gap between the elements and the indexes should be in line 
Like that https://ibb.co/m0KvtJ9

Doing that I always end up with a messed up gap or the border with a gap

Comment: The svg is adjustable and should be full width and height its in a 1:1 ratio

Comment: I added padding to `.konzitem` and update source, check out this.